# Setting Highcharts styledMode: true fails to load CSS

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm having problems with Highcharts styled mode - I don't understand how to use CSS to override the standard styling. My chart appears fine when styledMode is set to "false", but when I set to "true" all I get is a big black background.

It seems that the black background appears if the CSS file fails to load. This is what I've included within my site CSS:

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';
```

Here's my JFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7ua3450/

The Highcharts documentation [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/custom-themes-in-styled-mode) is really unclear on this - it tells me I need to create a custom CSS file but doesn't indicate where this is supposed to go...is it part of my site's general CSS file or somewhere else? And if the latter, how do I link to it?

Answer (score 0):

So, when `styledMode` has been set to true all inline styling are disabled, so the chart doesn't have any styling options - that's why the CSS options must be imported.

Take a look on how the default Highcharts CSS file it looks like: https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css

And take a look at this demo where all the options are just pasted - you can easily change each of the option.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a3torm6g/

```
chart: {
   styledMode: true
}
```